# Squared telecom parameters

Tags: power, telecommunication, noise

I observe that some telecommunication parameters are squared like noise power is $σ^2=-95\text{ dBm}$, and the amplifier coefficient $η^2=20\text{ dB}$. What is the meaning of the square? Can I remove it with mathematical calculations?

Comment: Why would you want to remove it with mathematical calculations ?

Answer (score 0):

It's common in physics and engineering to find that the energy of or the power transferred in some system is proportional to the square of some "signal" parameter, for example the voltage across a resistor, the pressure of a sound wave in a material, or the displacement of a mass connected to a spring.

Presumably the parameters you're looking at, $\sigma$ and $\eta$, are chosen to be proportional to some signal parameter, and then the power associated with them naturally is related to the square of these parameters.

Without knowing exactly what $\sigma$ and $\eta$ refer to (these symbols are used for many different things in different engineering fields), it's hard to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

**1.- standard deviation**

Without any further clarification from the question originator, and understandly assumint that the supplied values are related to signals, then it's reasonable to consider that `σ` stands for **standard deviation**.

Defition of **standard deviation** :

[https://www.math.net/standard-deviation#:~:text=Standard%20deviation%20Standard%20deviation%20is%20a%20statistical%20measure,values%20tend%20to%20be%20close%20to%20the%20mean.](https://www.math.net/standard-deviation#:%7E:text=Standard%20deviation%20Standard%20deviation%20is%20a%20statistical%20measure,values%20tend%20to%20be%20close%20to%20the%20mean.)

`mean` `variance` `standard deviation` `covariance` all concisely explained here :

https://www.mun.ca/biology/scarr/Mean_&_Variance.html

**2.- Signals with null DC**

In Communications, wireless modulated signals, radiated received by antennas, over-the-air sinals, as well as spectral noise, have **null DC values**.

**Radiated** Electromagnetic fields do not have DC.

Indeed noise and signals can and are often biased, on circuit boards there are plenty of examples to be found.

These are **conducted**, not radiated, signals.

**3.- dB dBm clarification**

In the context of this question, since the question originator starts equating squared `σ` and `η` to `dBm` and `dB` values, such practice is often found in literature for signals and noise with null DC component.

`dBm` and `dB` are often the short for `dBmW` and `dBW` that it's assumed this way there's no way to confuse them with `dBmV` and `dBV`.

Experts advise, in case of any doubt, when mixing power `W` and Volts `V` in same text, to use the whole expressions `dBmW` instead of `dBm` and `dBW` instead of `dBW` when referring to **signal power** and the equivalent with Volts when **signal amplitude levels** referred.

**4.- Signal to Power**

So `σ` is commonly assigned to signal deviation and `η` to noise deviation.

So when both signal `s` and noise `n` have null mean values, then taking the absolute values `abs(s)` `abs(n)` both fall  most of the time, statistically speaking, below certain levels.

This is, most of the times one measures `s` and `n` the readings of `s` and `n` below certain `abs()` level, now squared are equivalently proportional to **power level** but not equal.

The **proportionality factor** between the square of the values and power is the pervasive **impedance**.

All types of matter have (electrical) impedance.

**5.- Power measurements require known impedance(s)**

Circuit imedances are measured in Ohms = **Ω** (Omega, last character of Greek alphabet, as in [Rev22:13](https://forwhatsaiththescriptures.org/2017/01/12/alpha-and-omega/#:%7E:text=Revelation%2022%3A13%3A%20%E2%80%9C%20I%20am%20Alpha%20and%20Omega%2C,it%20would%20be%2C%20%E2%80%9CI%20am%20A%20and%20Z.%E2%80%9D)).

RF and microwave systems are mostly built with the following  impedances: **75Ω** for VHF some UHF, and **50Ω** system impedances, alothough there are plenty of **50Ω** for UHF systems.

So the **averaged power**, in a wide sense (rms? avg? another question),

is **squared amplitude over impedance**

However, accademia often obviate system impedances and tacitally assume **1Ω** allowing a lot more theory to be conveyed in the same text.

When one reads `-95dBm` for a sigma square probably means a weak signal, because dBm is another short for `dBmW`.

**30dBmW = 0 dBW   means   1mW = 1e-3W**

**6.- Disambiguation circuit impedance and wave impedance**

Matter is characterised by different values of impedance.

Signals impedances **in general**, are often referred as

`Z = R +1j*X`,

`R` **resistance** and `X` **reactance**

**Z** (Ω) directly relates **Voltage** (Volts) and **Current** (Amperes).

However **electromagnetic waves**, contrary to **acoustic waves**, travel without need of matter presence.

Then there are books that use `η` **in a particular way** as **electromagnetic wave impedance** also in `Ω` `Ohm`  :

**wave impedance** is the ratio between `|E|` electric field and `|H|` magnetic field

**electric field units `[V/m]`**

**mangetic field units `[A/m]`**

`B` is not magnetic field, but **magnetic flux**.

magnetic flux as `H * A` , `A` : area, square feet, square meters . B is not H/A

https://www.vedantu.com/physics/magnetic-flux

**B units : Tesla [T]**

```
 1 T = 1Wb/sqm =1N/(C * (m/s)) = 1N/(A * m)

Weber [Wb] : 1 Wb = 1 V·s = 1 T·m2 = 1 J/A = 10e8 Mx 

Maxwell [Mx]
```

`sqm` square meter, same as `m2`

Air / vacuum (wave, aka intrinsic) impedance is the wave impedance of mobile phone signals encounter when propagating through atmosphere : about `377Ω`.

`η` as wave impedance is often also found in literature as `Z0`.

when `Z0` values depart from standard values as the ones shown above it may referred with variable names like `Z1` `Z2` .. for instance in impedance transformers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: details added .